# What is this antenna on the ISS?

Tags: iss

And why is it moving? Doesn't make very much sense to me, a moving antenna. Or is it kind of radar that is checking  for dangerous objects? These are screen shots from this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtU_mdL2vBM).

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you see it's moving?

Comment: I took the screenshots, its from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtU_mdL2vBM

Comment: Ah, I see now. Well, the angle under which the antenna is rotating clearly forms a cone over the earths surface, so it must be some kind of communication anntenna.

Comment: This question is a better fit for space exploration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked on https://space.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @J.Chomel Better asked or should be asked on another site is not a Stack Exchange reason for closing. Off topic, because the question is *simply not about Astronomy* is however a very good reason!

Comment: @uhoh, sorry, then it could be migrated? I am not familiar with the process behind this. I will think twice next time when I propose to close something.

Comment: @J.Chomel oh no need to be sorry. SE sites often have some overlap, there aren't always well defined borders of on-topic-ness. In those cases it's generally up to the OP to decide if they'd like to move the question manually (copy paste text then delete in old location). In that case a helpful comment suggesting to the OP to move where they are more likely to get an answer usually comes first. Sometimes a moderator will decide to migrate also. But as users, we should vote to close for the standard reasons. In this case, I think simply the off-topic-ness reason is correct; not about Astronomy.

Answer (score 1):

That is [RapidScat](http://winds.jpl.nasa.gov/missions/RapidScat/), described in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8742/12102) in the Space Exploration SE.

[image]